# How to create a .then loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm new to the .then concept in javascript. I would like to know if it's possible to create a `for loop` with i number of `.then`'s

```
request.send(myRequest)
    .then(r => console.log(r, 0))
    .then(r => console.log(r, 1))
    .then(r => console.log(r, 2))
    .then(r => console.log(r, 3))
    .then(r => console.log(r, 4))
```

Rather than a manual workaround like this, I would like to create than chain of `.then`'s dynamically, so that it would be possible to execute `.then` `i` number of times with an `i++`

Yes.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no dependencies between promises you can use **promise.all([promise1,promise2]).then((arrayofresult)=>{})**.

Or you can make use of another external library [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be sequential you can always do something like that:

```
async function doSomeAsyncStuff(r, i, max) {
  if( i < max ) {
     await soSomeOtherAsyncStuff();

     return doSomeAsyncStuff(r, i+1, max )
  }
}

request.send(myRequest)
.then(r => {
   return doSomeAsyncStuff(r, i, 10)
})
```

But it always depends on the actual use-case how you want to solve the ideally.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, I think you are looking for a dynamic way to write promise chain.Here is a simple example. Here I've shown a way to do this stuff. You can tailor it according to your need.Here is the basic.

```js
function request(data){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => resolve(data))
}

var arrData = [1,2,3,4]

arrData.reduce((initial,data,index)=>initial.then(r => 
    {
       console.log(r);return request(data)

    }),Promise.resolve(0)).then(data=>console.log(data))
```